# Store variable from Javascript in R Shiny App

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

Right now I have a nice R Shiny app that is able to create a pdf from parts of it using a piece of javascript. However right now it just automatically downloads.

```
js <- "
$(document).on('shiny:sessioninitialized', function(event) {
  $('#printPdf_CA').click(function () {
    domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('mainOrder_CA'))
      .then(function (blob) {
        var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', [$('#mainOrder_CA').width(), $('#mainOrder_CA').height()]);
        pdf.addImage(blob, 'PNG', 0, 0, $('#mainOrder_CA').width(), $('#mainOrder_CA').height());
        pdf.save($('#name').val() + '.pdf');
      });
  });
});
"
```

I want to be able to store it locally (either as a file in a relative directory OR as a variable in the Shiny app) and then give the user the choice to either print it to pdf(like above) OR send it over email to a chosen adress (using the emayili package from R). I allready tried Shiny.setInputValue(), but that did not work at all (even just sending a number from the javascript didn't seem to work, but maybe I am doing something wrong here.

I would really appreciate your help!

**EDIT**
I made Shiny.setinputValue() work, but don't know how to write it to a temporary .pdf file from the field. I also wonder if this still is officially recognized as a pdf or if there was some information loss when moved to R

**EDIT 2:**
Basically I manage to send the PDF to R as a shiny input with the following adjusted code:

```
$(document).on('shiny:sessioninitialized', function(event) {
var pdf
  $('#storePDF').click(function () {
    domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('Capture'))
      .then(function (blob) {
        pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', [$('#Capture').width(), $('#Capture').height()]);
        pdf.addImage(blob, 'PNG', 0, 0, $('#Capture').width(), $('#Capture').height());
        Shiny.setInputValue('pdf', pdf)
      });
  });
});
```

Now I would just need to be able to create a PDF in R from this. However in R the resulting file ist just a list of lists and various components (a large structure probably describing the PDF in some way).

Printing this to console gives the following output:

```
$internal
$internal$collections
$internal$collections$addImage_images
$internal$collections$addImage_images$`0`
$internal$collections$addImage_images$`0`$alias
[1] 1916164677

$internal$collections$addImage_images$`0`$w
[1] 1905

$internal$collections$addImage_images$`0`$h
[1] 880

$internal$collections$addImage_images$`0`$cs
[1] "DeviceRGB"

$internal$collections$addImage_images$`0`$bpc
[1] 8

..... And much more......
```

is there any way to turn this kind of thing into a pdf?

**Edit 3:**

My half decent solution for anyone interested was to just move the "blob" to Shiny (Shiny.setInputValue)

than use the base64decoder

read image using magick::image_read
and write to tempfile pdf using magick::image_write

Answer (score 2):

Next time you copy from one of my post, please give the link, this would have been easier.

You can proceed as follows, using base64 encoding/decoding:

```
library(shiny)
library(base64enc)

js <- "
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#printPdf').click(function () {
    domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('frame_print'))
      .then(function (blob) {
        var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', [$('#frame_print').width(), $('#frame_print').height()]);
        pdf.addImage(blob, 'PNG', 0, 0, $('#frame_print').width(), $('#frame_print').height());
        pdf.save('test.pdf');
      });
  });
  $('#getPdf').click(function () {
    domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('frame_get'))
      .then(function (blob) {
        var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', [$('#frame_get').width(), $('#frame_get').height()]);
        pdf.addImage(blob, 'PNG', 0, 0, $('#frame_get').width(), $('#frame_get').height());
        var b64 = pdf.output('datauristring');
        Shiny.setInputValue('b64pdf', b64);
      });
  });
});
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"),
    tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dom-to-image/2.6.0/dom-to-image.min.js"),
    tags$script(js)
  ),
  br(),
  actionButton("printPdf", "PRINT", class = "btn-primary"),
  div(
    id = "frame_print",
    style = "border: 2px solid black;",
    h3("Click on the button to print me as PDF")
  ),
  br(),
  actionButton("getPdf", "GET", class = "btn-info"),
  div(
    id = "frame_get",
    style = "border: 2px solid red;",
    h3("Click on the button to get me as PDF")
  ),
  br(),
  conditionalPanel(
    "input.b64pdf !== undefined",
    downloadButton("dwnld")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  observeEvent(input[["getPdf"]], {
    showNotification(
      "PDF base64 string stored in `input$b64pdf`.",
      type = "message"
    )
  })
  
  output[["dwnld"]] <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "Test.pdf",
    content = function(file){
      mybase64 <- input[["b64pdf"]]
      conn <- file(file, open = "wb")
      base64decode(substr(mybase64, 51L, nchar(mybase64)), output = conn)
      close(conn)
    }
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I will link it next time. Found a way using "magick" already. Just sent the blob data to R and decoded it there.